# Text in Custom buttons randomly not centered vertically

Tags: html, css, button

I have a form where I use several plus and minus buttons to add new elements to the form as needed by the user.  I've used a custom button style.  I've used this site to get the necessary css to make sure the text is centered. But this only seems to work in some instances of the button.

```js
function unhide(id) {
  var myForm = document.forms.mrform;
  var myControls = myForm.elements[id.concat('[]')];
  for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
    var aControl = myControls[i];
    if ($(aControl).is(':hidden')) {
      $("#".concat(id.concat(i+1).replace(/ /g, "_"))).show();
   break;
    }
  }
}

function hide(id) {
  var myForm = document.forms.mrform;
  var myControls = myForm.elements[id.concat('[]')];
  for (var i = myControls.length; i > 0 ; i--) {
    var aControl = myControls[i];
    if ($(aControl).is(':visible')) {
      $("#".concat(id.concat(i+1).replace(/ /g, "_"))).hide();
   break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.pmbutton {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 17px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='mrform' action='report_generator.php' method='post' autocomplete='off' onkeypress='return event.keyCode != 13;'>
<table class='subform'>
  <tr id='Objective_Item1'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #1 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'><button type='button' class='pmbutton' onclick='unhide("Objective Item")'>+</button><button type='button' class='pmbutton' onclick='hide("Objective Item")'>-</button></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item2' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #2 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item3' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #3 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item4' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #4 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item5' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #5 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item6' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #6 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item7' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #7 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item8' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #8 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item9' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #9 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
  <tr id='Objective_Item10' class='hideme'><td class='prompt text'>Objective Item #10 :</td><td class='input'><input class='inputbox text' type='text' name='Objective Item[]'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The functionality is fine, but the text is not vertically centered in the button in some instances and IS in others.  Seems to be a single pixel off in random buttons. I've viewed it in Firefox and Chrome (which seems to be worse).  Any suggestions as to the cause?

Edit: Adding an image of several renderings of the same button on one page of the site.  The only property I change between some of them is the background color.  Both vertical and horizontal alignment vary, it seems.

[image: Button Renderings]

[image: Additional Button renderings]

Comment: I have updated answer with reason and how to overcome give it try and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you read. I am not a font professional and I'm giving the answer based on my several hours research on the topic. I might be wrong in some places and I will gladly accept any improvement of the answer.

**TL;DR**

In my opinion, your safest approach would be to create images of `+` and `−` and use them as buttons instead.

---

**How fonts work**

To answer your question you need to know how fonts work first.

Each character in the font is fitted into its own space container. In traditional metal type this container was the actual metal block of each character. The height of each character piece was uniform, allowing the characters to be set neatly into rows and blocks. This space is called "em-space" and it originates from the width of the uppercase `M` character. It was made so that the proportions of this letter would be square.

In digital type, em-space is defined like so:

- In an OpenType font it is usually set at 1000 units.
- In TrueType fonts it is by convention a power of two, generally set to 1024 or 2048 units.

When the font is used to set type, the em is scaled to the desired point size.

Each character in your font also has these elements:

- Baseline is the line which defines the bottom of the character. With certain exceptions like `g` and `q` characters do not cross the baseline.
- Cap height is the line which defines the top of a capital letter. Those are usually flat letters like `H` or `I`, whilst `O` or `A` might overshoot.
- X-height is the height of a lower-case letter. Typically, this is the height of the letter `x` in the font, hence the name.
- Ascender is the part of a lower-case letter that is taller than the font's x-height. Think of `b` and `d` characters.
- Descender is the portion of a letter that extends below the baseline of a font. I already mentioned `g` and `q`.

All those elements are contained inside em-space.

Now, what happens when you try to scale the font down to 10px (based on your `font-size: 10px;` setting). Unless you changed your browser settings, the browser default font size is 16px (1 em = 2048 units for Times New Roman you seemingly use).

But Times New Roman uses 1825 ascent and 443 descent, which makes 2268 units in a 2048 unit em-square on Windows. Mac seems to use the `HHead` values, which are the same for Times New Roman. Here's the screenshot showing those values:

[image: Times New Roman font info]

What does it mean? It means that when you specify `font-size: 10px` the actual size of Times New Roman would be absolutely different. If I'm right with my calculations, it would be `11.07421875` rounded down to `11px` (already an "ouch", right?)

**`line-height` and `vertical-align`**

Okay, next, when your `button` is rendered on screen, it can be composed of many lines, according to its width. Each line is made up of one or many inline elements (eg. `span` elements with different font settings) and is called a line-box. The height of a line-box is based on its children’s height. The browser computes the height for each inline element and chooses the tallest child as the "template" for the line-box. This ensures you see all the characters on your screen when the element is rendered.

This behavior differs from Word or Photoshop. In those programs, `line-height` is not based on line-box. Instead it is the distance between baselines. But in CSS it is not. In css your `line-height` is your line-box.

It should be noted, that CSS does not specify [default value of `line-height`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height). Default value is `normal`:

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2. The computed value is 'normal'.

And this is the specs for `vertical-align`:

> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

From all the information above we can conclude, that it's the content-area being centered vertically, not the character purely.

**Indeed**

I've checked `+` and `-` in font editing software and it looks like this:

[image: Plus and Hyphen in Times New Roman]

While `+` seems symmetrical, it's still lowered a bit inside it's content area; and `-` is lowered down towards baseline. So the answer for `-` is obvious. Based on everything I've researched and posted above - you will not be able to center it vertically, it will always be slightly lower. On small font sizes it might be a pixel or two; on huge font size you will see it right away.

Note, that the `-` you are used to typing (top right key on num pad; or key right of `0`) is not minus, it's `hyphen`. Minus and hyphen looks differently: `−` vs. `-`.

Would `− (minus)` look differently? It surely has more symmetry to it:

[image: Plus and Minus in Times New Roman]

Here you can see more clearly, that `+` and `− (minus)` are closer to the base line.

**Flexboxes as possible solution?**

Let's take a look at flexbox. When you define `display: flex`, a box is generated called `flex container`. In-flow children of a flex container are called `flex items` and are laid out inside flex lines.

> Unlike block and inline layout, whose layout calculations are biased to the block and inline flow directions, flex layout is biased to the flex directions.

[image: flex container and flex items]

Now, flex lines, apart from line-boxes, work differently:

> Once content is broken into lines, each line is laid out independently; flexible lengths and the justify-content and align-self properties only consider the items on a single line at a time.
>
> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line (after alignment due to align-self), and the lines are aligned within the flex container with the align-content property. In a single-line flex container, the cross size of the line is the cross size of the flex container, and align-content has no effect. The main size of a line is always the same as the main size of the flex container’s content box.

So, when you define `align-items: center`,

> The flex item’s margin box is centered in the cross axis within the line.

And finally, [if I understood the specification correctly](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines), when you specify `align-items: center`, the baseline is generated dynamically, allowing you to actually perfectly center the `+` and `−`.

**In conclusion**

You should use flexboxes and use `div`, not a `button`, as `button` seems to behave differently (I'd welcome a documented suggestion why). Even though if you specify huge numbers (like `width` and `height` to `400px` and `font-size` to `750px`) you will see slight shifting towards the bottom. But on small sizes everything seems to work perfectly.

In my opinion, your safest approach would be to create images of `+` and `−` and use them as buttons instead.

---

**Sources** I researched:

- http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/The_EM_Square.html
- https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-line
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines

App to show the font info - https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/

Comment: Further to this, when using a 'plus' character, its opposite is 'minus', not 'hyphen'. Plus and minus in most fonts will better align with each other vertically.

Comment: @Arthur thank you, I completely missed the fact, that it's hyphen and not minus. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also, monospace fonts have the characteristic where each letter/symbol have identical widths. I.e. an 'i' will take up the same space as an 'm'.

Comment: @Illdapt width-wise, yes. Not height-wise.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer.  This explains why the text is not well centered.  I changed the `-` to `&minus;` which fixed the misalignment between the two. However, this does not explain why there is a difference from one + button to the other. (See my additional image in my question edit).  I have decided to take your advice and use an image for the buttons instead.  But I'm interested in solving or at least explaining the initial problem.

Comment: The difference between alignment from one button to the next, eliminates the use of padding to "fix" the centering, which is why doing so (as suggested elsewhere) would not solve my issue.

Comment: As an experiment, I just changed the font size from 11 to 12 as I thought it might have something to do with using a non-standard size for the font(s).  This made all the buttons consistent in their horizontal alignment (though they're not centered), but now the buttons are inconsistent in their vertical alignment in much the same way as they were horizontally before.  Very strange behavior.  I'm going to try changing them to divs.  Will report back.

Comment: The inconsistencies are because of rounding the font size during scaling. I think it's somehow stacking to the previous scaling and therefore it's off by a pixel to the left and then to the right.

Comment: Changed them to divs which had no effect.  I had the same thought about the scaling, so I double checked my monitor to make sure I didn't have any.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be because of the button element itself:
When placing the `+` inside a seperate span, and aligning the span perfectly in the center,
by using flexboxes, 
the `+`is still *not exactly* in the center. When I do the same with a div element,
the `+` is *exactly* centered.
Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukr20cg/1/) to see what I mean.
Therefore I recommend using a div with a click event instead of a button.

Also, if you want have a minus sign which is vertically aligned at the same height as the plus,
you should use `&minus;` instead of `-` inside your element.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've done more research and updated my answer to include flexboxes.

Comment: I made the change to the `&minus;` which fixed the disparity between the plus and the minus.  Thank you.

Comment: It's still unclear since in php you should make mathematical functions to get the value like     1-2 = -1  in first colum then second... In such case how to adapt all the answers posted here to write  + - in table i.e. It will work if the code is HTML code not php output.

Comment: @Creative87 In the case you want a `-` to be replaced with `minus;`, you could simply use Javascript to modify the output before applying it. `text = output.replace('-', '&minus;')`

Answer (score 1):

You need specify the font-family in .pmbutton,

you can choose a widely using [web safe](https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/) font or you can declare your own [font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

```
.pmbutton {
   font-family:arial;
}
```

Comment: Arial puts it's `+` sign slightly above the median; it's pixel off towards the top in OP's settings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do instead of hard coded `height` and `width`, use `padding` for the spacing.. If the `font-size` is `10px` then just give it a padding of `4px`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to place your values in central position 
According to HTML code you have posted above 
You can't place your Text in center position unless you do the following:

```
<td class = "test" align = "center">+<td>
```

You should use align="center" to get text in center position and don't use CSS for this it will not work just use it as above 
Now you need to place text in center position vertically 
This step can be achieved by CSS

```
.test { padding-top = 2px; padding-bottom = 2px;}
```

As above in CSS  vertical position is adjusted by padding.

Another way if not work with HTML5

Use span inside the tag

```
<td class ="test"><span>+</span></td>
```

Then use CSS

```
.test > span { padding-top = 2px; padding-bottom = 2px; padding-right = 2px padding-left = 2px;}
```

Update

Look in case you ask about Mac OS and iPhone also the reset of this device so here my advice 
Don't used td tag with these devices they will not work fine and this related to app development not for devices itself.  If you use Firefox on iPhone it may work fine 
So use this type of tags
Example

```
<dl>
<dt>Coffee</dt>
<dd>Black hot drink</dd>
<dt>Milk</dt>
<dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

dt  is better than td

Reason :

Possible reasons for this behavior 
I search around and ask some friends why this could be happening in some browsers while other not?
And I got this conclusion:

This is because sometimes Safari webview Zooms text automatically because  it though  its a good idea.

To disable this Use this  CSS Style:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

Now your characters should be displayed without interrupting .

Comment: `align` property is not supported in HTML5 and therefore `+` will not be centered horizontally.

Comment: I have updated answer with another I think it should work fine

Comment: sorry, I still think it's crutch-based development. The default font is different in different browser on different machines; your solution will hardly work on macos... Besides, you fail to explain the cause of OP's problem (and he's asking about the cause)

Comment: He use td and by the way td tag on not just mac also on iPhone don't work fine and don't display symbols right  I just try to give away around that  but if you search for the cause not for solution then you right my answer is not the cause.

Comment: I have updated answer with the cause. If you have update or new ideas then add comment to let me know.